# What is Package Variable?

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, package

Someone please answer the 2 questions below:

1. What are *Package Variables*? I know what *Global Variables* are but I haven't heard about package variables.
2. In a 500 line procedure, I got an error for 212th line with ORA-01204 like that... How do I fix this issue?

I answered by using Exception we can overcome and By using `DBMS_Profiler` we can check which line got error. But Interviewer said its wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my thoughts -

1. May be it is variables defined inside the package body.
2. dbms_profiler is used to capture performance bottlenecks. its not used for debug.

Comment: So what will be the  answer??. Next time if this questions comes I need to answer...

Comment: which answer you are looking for ? 1 - already answered. 2. to debug a procedure, use tools like toad, sql developer, add breakpoints and then debug. Or  you can add dbms out put statements to check which is a point of failure if its a small package.

Answer (score 0):

These are Variables declared in a package and are maintained throughout a session.

Hope this helps. The references have more details into the structure and assignment of variables to packages and its uses.

References:

[Oracle PL/SQL](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/packages/package_vars.html)
[Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/package_declaration.htm)

Comment: What will be the answer for the 2nd Question